# Saving fields to a GlobalSet

Tags: plugin-development, globals

Can anyone suggest on how to programatically save fields to a GlobalSet?
I’ve been following this: [Programatically Adding Fields to a Layout](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6587/programatically-adding-fields-to-a-layout/18052#18052)

But, doesn’t seem to work with a global?

I am doing the following :

- Create a new field group - works
- Assign fields to field group - works
- Create global set - works
- Create field layout - works
- Create field layout tab - works
- Set fields to layout tab - nope

.

```
// get all the fields from company info fieldgroup
$Fields = $FieldGroup->getFields();
// Get field layout
$GlobalSetLayout = $GlobalSet->getFieldLayout();


// Create tab model
$GlobalSetLayoutTab = new FieldLayoutTabModel();
$layout = craft()->fields->getLayoutByType(ElementType::GlobalSet);
$GlobalSetLayoutTab->setLayout($layout);
$GlobalSetLayoutTab->setFields($Fields);

// Set the tab's fields
$GlobalSetLayoutTab->setFields($fields);

// setTabs() expects an array
$layoutTabs[] = $GlobalSetLayoutTab;

// Now, set the tabs back in the layout.
$layout->setTabs($layoutTabs);
```

Not sure if part of the issue is because Globals don’t exactly have a “tab”, but looking at others in the database it does seem to have one with the name “Content”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// Generate name and handle.
$globalSetName = "My Global Set";
$globalSetHandle = lcfirst(str_replace(" ","", ucwords($globalSetName)));

// Create a global set
$globalSet= new GlobalSetModel();
$globalSet->name = $globalSetName;
$globalSet->handle = $globalSetHandle;

// get all the fields from  fieldgroup
$fields = $fieldGroup->getFields();

// Get ids of the fields.
$fieldIds = array();
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    $fieldIds[] = $field->id;
}

// Assemble the field layout
$globalSetLayout = craft()->fields->assembleLayout(
    array(
        'Content' => $fieldIds,
    )
);

// Set the field layout type.
$globalSetLayout->type = ElementType::GlobalSet;

// Set field layout on global set.
$globalSet->setFieldLayout($globalSetLayout);

// Save global set.
craft()->globals->saveSet($globalSet);
```

Comment: Works perfect thank you Brad, just needed to change `foreach ($fields $field)` to `foreach ($fields as $field)`

Comment: Oops... fixed!!