# Add a field to a global set

Tags: plugin-development

is there a way to add a field to a global set by code ? I figured out how to create a global:

```
$global = new GlobalSetModel();
$global->name = 'GlobalName';
$global->handle = 'globalHandle';
craft()->globals->saveSet($global)
```

But I can't figure out how to add a field to this newly create global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/764/57) for how to add a field to a user's field layout.

Users, Globals, Tags, Categories, etc. are all [elements](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/working-with-elements) in Craft so they behave very similarly.

You can also check out Craft's own [InstallService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/InstallService)'s private `_createDefaultContent()` method for examples on how Craft creates the default content on a fresh install of Craft.